# is android map v3 API for Mobile App or only for mobile/desktop browser? What should I use for Mobile App which makes use of Maps: V2 or V3?

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile, google-maps-api-3

I am about to implement an Android App which will use google Maps. Can someone please clarify whether I can use
Google Maps API V3 for our Mobile App or I should use API V2. I could not find it written any where , what exactly V2 and V3 will be used for?

is V2 for Mobile Apps and V3 for browsers Apps (mobile and desktop browsers both) ?

Thanks,
Satendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and found developers.google.com/maps/faq#whatis link . Goto this link and read the answer of this question "How do I deliver Maps applications on mobile devices?" . It clears the query.

Answer (score 0):

Google have 2 version of google map, for mobile and for web.

1. Google map V2 is for mobile *(android,ios)* : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/
2. Google map V3 is for web: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

You should use google map v2 for mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but is it mentioned somewhere on Goggle's website?

Comment: I did not find it. I want to know where google has mentioned it officially that V2 is for Android Apps and V3 is for browsers?

Comment: Android has V1 google map but now active version is V2. You have google map for three platforms (android,ios,web) and each of them have own version of google map.

Comment: Thanks Milan but that also does not tell where Google has mentioned it officially. I searched and found https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#whatis
link . Goto this link and read the answer of this question "How do I deliver Maps applications on mobile devices?" . It clears the query.